# Multiplicative alphametic: This is too hard

Tags: no-computers, alphametic

- Every letter and every question mark  stands for a digit in base-10 representation
- Different letters stand for different digits
- Question marks are placeholders and stand for arbitrary digits (that also may occur for letters)
- Leading digits are always non-zero.

  ```
          THIS
         *  IS
          ----
         ??TOO
        HARD?
        ------
        ??????
  ```

Which digit does each letter represent? 
(Please present the full analysis how these digits can be determined.)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the format of your question. Is there a reason that `??TOO` and `HARD?` do not align vertically? Why is `THIS * IS` all on one line?

Comment: I'm not familiar with this notation. should there be a 0 behind `HARD?` ?

Comment: `THIS * S = ??TOO`,   `THIS * I = HARD?`   and the alignment is shifted because `IS = I*10 + S`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the OO in TOO, we have S*S mod 10 = I*S + (SS div 10) mod 10.

We know S$\neq$0 (otherwise S=O=0). We also have I$\neq$1 (otherwise "HARD?" only has 4 digits).

Discarding solutions where more than one of I,S,O has the same digit, the above equation produces (I,S,O) = (5,7,9), (6,8,4), and (7,9,1).

**Case 1: (I,S,O) = (5,7,9)**

In TOO, T = 7H+3 mod 10.

With H$\neq$0 in "HARD?" and T$\neq$0 in THIS, and discarding solutions where more than 1 letter has the same digit, we have (T,H) = (4,3) (R=7, discard) or (1,4) ("HARD?" will only have 5 digits, discard).

No solution.

**Case 2: (I,S,O) = (6,8,4)**

In TOO, T = 8H+5 mod 10.

From TOO, T=8H+5 mod 10.
From "HARD?", D=0 and R=6H+4 mod 10.

Using the equations for T and R, T$\neq$0, H$\neq$0, R$\neq$0 and eliminating duplicate digits, we have (T,H,R) = (9,3,2) (A=6, discard) or (1,7,3) (R=6, discard).

No solution.

**Case 3: (I,S,O) = (7,9,1)**

Following the same procedure as before, T=9H+7 mod 10, and R=7H+5 mod 10.

Eliminating possibilities as before, we're left with (T,H,R) = (4,3,6) or (2,5,0) (H=5, discard).

The only solution is THIS=4379, IS=79, ??TOO=39411, HARD?=30653, ??????=345941.

```
            4379
           *  79
          ------
           39411
          30653
          ------
          345941
```

Substituting our letters, we get the (totally meaningless) statements:

```
            THIS
           *  IS
          ------
           HSTOO
          HARDH
          ------
          HTDSTO
```

Answer (score 5):

Let $P_i^j$ be the product of the $i$th digit in the first number and the $j$th digit in the second number.  Let $C_i^j$ be the carry over of $P_i^j$, and let $D_i^j$ be the digit in the result.

For example, $P_3^2$ is the product of H X I.

First off, we can see that $S \notin \{0,1,5,6\}$ since $S \ne O$. Also, if $I \ne 1$ since the second product line is not identical to THIS.  So $I \notin \{0,1\}$.

If S=3, then $P_1^1=D_1^1=O=9$ and $C_1^1=0$.  We know that $D_2^1=O=9$ as well, but no value for $I$ results in $D_2^1=9$.

If S=4, then $P_1^1=16 \implies D_1^1=O=6$ and $C_1^1=1$. But then we need $P_2^1=I \times S+C_1^1$ to end in 6, which means $I \times S$ ends in 5, which is impossible with an even S.

Thus, $S \in \{2,7,8,9\}$.

### Assume S=2

Thus $P_1^1=D_1^1=O=4$ and $C_1^1=0$. We know that $D_2^1=O=4$ as well, so we know that $I=7$. The means that $D=0$.  Since $THIS \times 2$ is a five digit number, we know $T \ge 5$.  Also, we know that $C_2^1=1$ and $D_3^1=T$ where $P_3^1=2H+1$ so T is odd.

If T=5, then $2H=4$ only works with $H \in \{2,7\}$, both of which are taken.

Thus, T=9 and $2H=8 \implies H=4$.  But then $THIS \times I=9472 \times 7 = 66304$ which means H=A. Contradiction.

### Assume S=7

$P_1^1=49 \implies D_1^1=O=9$ and $C_1^1=4$.  To get $D_2^1=9$, we need $I \times S$ to end in 5.  This only works when $I=5$.  So $P_2^1=I\ times S+C_1^1=5 \times 7+4+39 \implies C_2^1=3$ which means $T=7H+3 \mod 10$

- $H=1 \implies T=0$, but T can't be 0.
- $H=2 \implies T=7$, but 7 is already taken by S
- $H=3 \implies T=4$, but $THIS \times I=4357\times 5=21785\implies A=7$ is already taken by S.
- $H=4 \implies T=1$, but $THIS \times I=1457\times 5=7285 \implies H=0$.
- $H=6 \implies T=5$, but 5 is already taken by I
- $H=8 \implies T=9$, but 9 is already taken by O

Contradiction.

### Assume S=8

$P_1^1=64 \implies D_1^1=O=4$ and $C_1^1=6$.  To get $D_2^1=4$, we need $I \times S$ to end in 8.  This only works when I=6.

Now, $C_2^1=5$, so $T=8H+5 \mod 10$.  This means that T is odd and $H\ne5$

- $H=1 \implies T=3$, but $THIS \times I = 3168 \times 6=19008 \implies R=A$
- $H=2 \implies T=1$, but $THIS \times I = 1268 \times 6=4608 \implies H=0$
- $H=3 \implies T=9$, but $THIS \times I = 9368 \times 6=56208 \implies H=5$
- $H=7 \implies T=1$, but $THIS \times I = 1768 \times 6=11208 \implies H=1$
- $H=9 \implies T=7$, but $THIS \times I = 7968 \times 6=47808 \implies H=4$

Contradiction

### Therefore S=9

$P_1^1=81 \implies D_1^1=O=1$ and $C_1^1=8$.  To get $D_2^1=1$, we need $I \times S$ to end in 3.  This only works when $I=7$.

Now, $C_2^1=7$, so $T=9H+7 \mod 10$.

- $H=2 \implies T=5$, but $THIS \times I = 5279 \times 7=36953 \implies R=9$ which is already taken by S
- $H=4 \implies T=3$, but $THIS \times I = 3479 \times 7=24353 \implies R=3$ which is already taken by T
- $H=5 \implies T=2$, but $THIS \times I = 2579 \times 7=18053 \implies H=1$
- $H=6 \implies T=1$, but 1 is already taken by O
- $H=8 \implies T=9$, but 9 is already taken by S

Thus,  $H=3 \implies T=4$.

```
    4379
   *  79
    ----
   39411
  30653
  ------
  345941
```

Answer (score 2):

The answer is:

> `4379`
>   `*  79`
>  `------`
>   `39411`
>  `30653` 
>  `------`
>  `345941`

So the letters/digits are:

> `0 = A`
>  `1 = O`
>  `3 = H`
>  `4 = T`
>  `5 = D`
>  `6 = R`
>  `7 = I`
>  `9 = S`

When approaching this, I first decided to answer this question:

For any integer i between 1 and 9 inclusive, what s^2 + i*10 gives us a number where the ones and tens places hold the same digit?

0 Would fit the bill, but ??TOO is != 0, so S can't be 0.
1 no
2 -- Maybe if I = 7  (O = 4)
3 no
4 Tens place of 4x4 is odd, so no value of I would work.
S Tens place of 5 squared is not 0 or 5
6 Tens place of 6x6 is odd, so no value of I would make this work.
7 -- Maybe if I = 5  (O = 9)
8 -- Maybe if I = 6  (O = 4)(or S = 1, but I can't be 1 because THIS is not  HARD?)
9 -- Maybe if I = 7  (O = 1)

Then, I tried the possible combinations that I found.

> Starting the highest possible values for S and I made the most sense to me, which led to the answer.  When testing out values of H when I = 7 and S = 9, 3 is the only one that fits.  We already know some of the other letters in this test case, so we don't have to test everything.  Finally, with only a few values to try, we find that T = 4 fits.

I was hoping that he last row would spell something if we backfilled some of the digits with letters.

> But all we get is htdsto.